# Let $a, b, c ∈ R$, and let $M$ be the following matrix. Prove that $(a + c)^2 − 4ac ≥ 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions

Let $a, b, c ∈ R$, and let $M$ = \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
b & c 
\end{pmatrix}

Prove that M has a real eigenvalue

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The characteristic equation is
$$\lambda^2 -(a+c)\lambda + \left(ac-b^2\right) = 0.$$

What is the discriminant of the quadratic here (in particular its sign), and what does that tell you about the roots?

Comment: I think I understand, since it is positive, then M should have a real eigenvalue, right?

Comment: Pretty much! It is *non-negative*, and yes, a real quadratic with a non-negative discriminant has a real root.